Non-parametric tatistical test and post hoc for two-way layout with longitudinal data?
I have questions about the approach in statistics that I'm taking for my experiment. However, I do not have a good understanding of statistics, so I opted to add more information than less.
My questions:

Did I choose the right statistical test?
Did I choose the right post-hoc test?
Is my post-hoc plan reasonable?
Should I have set all the pretest scores to zero and the posttest scores to be distance from (the original) pretest scores? I feel safe in assuming that before the treatment, all groups knew the same amount of information about the topic tested.

————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
I want to find out whether one teaching method is better than another for short-term information retention, as measured by change in questionnaire score from before to after undergoing a teaching method. These are the steps I took:

I formed three groups of participants: A, B, and C (control).
All participants took a Likert scale questionnaire ("pretest") before any treatment.
Group A underwent teaching method A, Group B underwent teaching method B, and Group C sat and did nothing. (All treatments took the same amount of time.)
All participants took the same questionnaire ("posttest").


Also, the sample sizes of these groups are not the same.

From my understanding, the above setup has one between-subjects factor (teaching method) and one within-subjects factor (time). I would have done a mixed ANOVA to check for statistically significant differences, but the samples failed the assumption of homogeneity of variances (Levene's test via pingouin, p-value < 0.05), so I used nparLD instead (link), as it is nonparametric. Its output:
# intervention    refers to teaching method
# test            refers to when the questionnaire was taken

Model: 
F1 LD F1 Model 
 
Call: 
score_sum ~ intervention * test

Relative Treatment Effect (RTE):

Wald-Type Statistc (WTS):
                  Statistic df      p-value
intervention       12.59902  2 1.837208e-03
test               58.19597  1 2.372640e-14
intervention:test  53.04024  2 3.037095e-12

ANOVA-Type Statistc (ATS):
                  Statistic       df      p-value
intervention       6.866235 1.913117 1.253029e-03
test              58.195975 1.000000 2.372640e-14
intervention:test 17.873863 1.784542 8.128555e-08

Modified ANOVA-Type Statistic for the Whole-Plot Factors:
             Statistic      df1      df2     p-value
intervention  6.866235 1.913117 91.43445 0.001938697

Since the intervention:test p-value < 0.05, I interpreted this as showing a statistically significant difference in scores. To see where the statistical significances are, I will opt for the Games-Howell test, since it is non-parametric. I plan to compare the following:

Pretest of each treatment with its posttest.
Posttests of each treatment with each other.

Lastly, here's a sample of the data:
id     intervention   test       score_sum
331    A              pretest    -11
331    A              posttest   -14
398    A              pretest    -12
398    A              posttest    -7
422    B              posttest     9
422    B              pretest     12
447    B              posttest   -17
447    B              pretest    -18
765    C              pretest    -6
765    C              posttest   -22
864    C              pretest      7
864    C              posttest   -11

